# Text not sizing correctly on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, safari, font-size

I'm trying to sort some cross browser compatibility issues with my company website, but I've hit a brick wall.

On an iPhone (4, 4s, 5, 5c and 5s), the navigation in the header is displayed incorrectly, and is not resizing with the rest of the page.

On other mobile platforms, in (I think) the most used browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Dolphin, Opera), the text re-sizes in relation to the rest of the site and fits correctly.

To fix the problem, I've tried setting the `font-size` property by both `px` and `em`, but the result is the same either way.

Is this a known issue with iPhones/Safari? If so, does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix it?

Here is the CSS for that section of the page -

```
#header-navigation{
    bottom: -4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
}
#header-navigation ul.menu{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header-navigation li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 14px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#header-navigation li.last{
    padding-right: 0;
}
#header-navigation li a{
    color: #6A737B;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#header-navigation li a:hover,
#header-navigation li.current-menu-item a,
#header-navigation li.current-page-ancestor a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C41E3A;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is how the page looks on an iPhone5 (and here is what it should look like - http://www.dynedrewett.com).

[image: iPhones suck!]

Answer (score 1):

use the font size like **em** it will work fine. and make sure to add meta view port

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;minimum-scale=0.5,
   maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1;" />

  .example{
  font-size:1.2em;
   }
```

Comment: I tried `em` and that was also not working. I'll add the meta view port (was unaware of these) and see how I get on with that. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, that's well and truly ruined the site (for both iOS and Android)! The is huge to start with, and I cannot zoom out enough to make it fit at all.

Comment: with meta view port, you cannot zoom it, if you want zoom it, remove maximum-scal and user-scalable , if it is help full give me one up

Comment: I've removed everything apart from `width=device-width`, and the page still spills off of the edge of the screen. I think I'll just pass this to an external developer for now, as I need a quick resolution. No doubt I'll be able to see what they have done and hopefully I'll learn from that!